# Parallel Computation of Elements of an Array in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing

I have an array with at least 360 numbers and one function **func** which I want to call upon each one of them. Because the function takes some time to calculate, I'm looking for a way to parallelize these tasks. Because I have almost no experience with Node.JS, I am looking for some help on how to achieve this.

That is what's given

```
var geometrical_form = new paper.CompoundPath('...');
var angles = [0, ..., 360];
```

What I want is that the following functions are called for each angle

```
geometrical_form.rotate(angle[i]);
func(geometrical_form);
```

Comment: hey @Jstroke, it would be more helpful to understand your question if you include a code snippet in post which you tried are using at the moment.

Comment: Between I guess you are looking for nodejs worker threads. https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html